# Set list in view and recieve in controller without ajax or submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have list of data in my view and want to receive it in my controller without using ajax or submit button it seems to be use viewbag but to send data from view to controller
the problem is i have a lot of data sent in submit button but this list have data over the data which sent in submit button.
i try to use ajax with submit button but it work before submit action but i want to do the submit button action first.

```
<div>
       @Html.DropDownList("InvoiceNames", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"Invoices", new { id = "InvoiceNames" })



            @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id="MyForm"}))
            {


                <div class="row-form">
                    <table style="border:0px;">
                        <tr >
                    <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.Date</td>
                    <td style="border:0px;">
                        <input type="text" id="invoicedata" name="Date"  readonly="readonly" placeholder="Date" style="width: 130px !important;"/>
                        <input id="Invoiceid" name="Id" type="hidden" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.Store</td>
                    <td style="border:0px;">
                        <input id="StoreName" class="validate[required]" type="text" placeholder="Store Name">
                        <input id="storeid" name="MainStoreId" type="hidden" />
                    </td>

                    <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.InvoiceSerial</td>
                    <td style="border:0px;">
                        <input id="invoiceserial" class="validate[required]" type="text" placeholder="Serial" name="Serial">
                    </td>
                    <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.UserName</td>
                    <td style="border:0px;">
                        <input type="text" id="invoiceusername" value="" readonly="readonly" placeholder="user name"/>
                        <input id="usernid" name="UserId" type="hidden" />
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                        </div>

                <div class="row-form">
                    <table style="border:0px;" id="IncomeItems">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:0px;"></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.ProductCode</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.name</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.Unit</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.Count</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.Prices</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.Total</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.notes</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;">@Resources.Global.CustomCategories</td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                        <tr class="LastRow">
                            <td style="border:0px;"><a href="#categoryproductsearch" role="button" data-toggle="modal" id="search1" class="Itemsearch"><span class="icon-search"></span></a></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><input id="productcode0" name="Items[0].Name" class="ItemTxt" type="text" placeholder="@Resources.Global.ProductCode"></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><input id="productname0" name="Items[0].Count" class="ItemCount" type="text" placeholder="@Resources.Global.name"><input class="ItemHidden" id="productidhidden0" name="StoreTransactionDetails[0].ProductId" type="hidden" /></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><input id="unit0" class="Itemunit" type="text" placeholder="@Resources.Global.Unit"><input class="unitHidden" name="StoreTransactionDetails[0].UnitId" id="unitidhidden0" type="hidden" /></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><input id="count0" name="StoreTransactionDetails[0].Count" class="Itemcountmony" type="number" min="0" placeholder="@Resources.Global.Count"></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><input id="price0" name="StoreTransactionDetails[0].Price" class="Itemprice" type="number" min="0" placeholder="@Resources.Global.Prices"></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><input id="total0" name="StoreTransactionDetails[0].TotalPrice" type="text" class="Itemtotal" value="" readonly="readonly" placeholder="@Resources.Global.Total"/></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><input id="note0" class="Itemnote" name="StoreTransactionDetails[0].Description" type="text" placeholder="@Resources.Global.notes"></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><a href="#ProductCustomCategory" role="button"  class="btn btn-primary Choose" data-toggle="modal">@Resources.Global.Choose</a><input type="hidden" name="StoreTransactionDetails[0].StoreTransactionCustomCaregories" id="productcustcat0" class="customCategoriesHidden" /></td>
                            <td style="border:0px;"><a style="display: none" class="DelItem"><span class="icon-remove"></span></a></td>
                        </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            <div class="toolbar bottom TAC">
                <input type="submit" formaction='@Url.Action("AddInvoice", "StocksTree")' id="submit" class="btn btn-primary saveAcTree" value="@Resources.Global.submit"/>
                <input type="button" id="addnewone" class="btn btn-primary AddNewAcTree" value="@Resources.Global.addnewone"/>
                <input type="button" id="Rest" class="btn btn-warning cancelAcTree"value="@Resources.Global.Rest" />
                <a href="#DeleteConfirm" role="button" class="btn btn-primary DeleteTree" style="display: none;" data-toggle="modal">@Resources.Global.delete</a>
            </div>
            }
</div>
```

this in html

```
$(function () {
        function AddRow() {
            var row = $('#IncomeItems tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#IncomeItems tbody>tr:last');
            $(this).closest("tr").find(".DelItem").show();
            var count = $("#IncomeItems tbody>tr").length;
            $(row).find(':input').val('');
            $(this).unbind('focus');
            $(row).find('.ItemTxt').attr("name", "Items[" + (count - 1) + "].Name");
            $(row).find('.ItemCount').attr("name", "Items[" + (count - 1) + "].Count");
            $(row).find('.ItemTxt').attr("id", "productcode" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.ItemCount').attr("id", "productname" + (count - 1)); 
            $(row).find('.ItemHidden').attr("id", "productidhidden" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.ItemHidden').attr("name", "StoreTransactionDetails[" + (count - 1) + "].ProductId");
            $(row).find('.Itemunit').attr("id", "unit" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.unitHidden').attr("id", "unitidhidden" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.unitHidden').attr("name", "StoreTransactionDetails[" + (count - 1) + "].UnitId");
            $(row).find('.Itemcountmony').attr("id", "count" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.Itemcountmony').attr("name", "StoreTransactionDetails[" + (count - 1) + "].Count");
            $(row).find('.Itemprice').attr("id", "price" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.Itemprice').attr("name", "StoreTransactionDetails[" + (count - 1) + "].Price");
            $(row).find('.Itemtotal').attr("id", "total" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.Itemtotal').attr("name", "StoreTransactionDetails[" + (count - 1) + "].TotalPrice");
            $(row).find('.Itemnote').attr("name", "StoreTransactionDetails[" + (count - 1) + "].Description");
            $(row).find('.Itemnote').attr("id", "note" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.Itemsearch').attr("id", "search" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.customCategoriesHidden').attr("id", "productcustcat" + (count - 1));
            $(row).find('.customCategoriesHidden').attr("name", "StoreTransactionDetails[" + (count - 1) + "].StoreTransactionCustomCaregories");
            var fullcodeid = $(this).attr("id")
            $("#" + fullcodeid).live("keyup", function () {
                var idforsend = $("#" + fullcodeid).val()
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetProductWithFullCode", "StocksTree")',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { fullcode: idforsend },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var radwa = $("#" + fullcodeid).parent("td").siblings("td").children(".ItemCount").attr("id")
                        $("#" + radwa).val(data.Name)
                        $("#" + fullcodeid).parent("td").siblings("td").children(".ItemHidden").val(data.ProductID)
                    }
                });
            })

            return false;
        }
        $(".LastRow .ItemTxt").focus(AddRow);
```

this in java script to add new row in runtime

```
<div id="ProductCustomCategory" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>@Resources.Global.AddPackage</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="productCustomCategoryList">
    <input type="hidden" id="checkedvalues" />
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="ProductCustomCategorySave" class ="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">@Resources.Global.Save</button>
        <button id="AddCustomCategoryCancel" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">@Resources.Global.cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

    var bttn;
    $('.Choose').live("click", function () {
        bttn = $(this)
        var id =$(this).parent("td").siblings("td").children(".ItemHidden").val()
        $('#productCustomCategoryList').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomCategoriesProduct", "StocksTree")',
            data: { ProductID: id },
            success: function (result) {
                $(result).each(
                function () {
                    $("#productCustomCategoryList").append("<div><a><img src='/Content/images/forward_disabled.png' style='float:left' /></a><li><span>" + this.Name + "</li></span><ul id='" + this.CustomCategoryID + "'></ul><input type='hidden' value='" + this.CustomCategoryID + "'/></div>");
                });
            }
        });

        $('#ProductCustomCategory').attr('aria-hidden', false);
        $('#ProductCustomCategory').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $("#productCustomCategoryList a").live("click", function () {
        var parentId = $(this).siblings("input").val();
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
            $(".child" + parentId).remove();
            $(this).children("img").attr("src", "/Content/images/forward_disabled.png");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            $(this).children("img").attr("src", "/Content/images/arrow-down.png");

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCustomCategoryItems","StocksTree")', { customCategoryId: parentId }, function (result) {
                $(result).each(
                    function () {
                        $("#" + parentId).append("<div class='child" + this.CatID + "'><li><input class='a' type='radio' name='customcategoryitem" + this.CatID + "' id='" + this.CustomCategoryItemID + "'><span>" + this.Name_EN + "</span></li><ul id='" + this.CustomCategoryID + "'></ul><input type='hidden' value='" + this.CustomCategoryID + "'/></div>");
                    })
            }).done(function () {
                if ($('#checkedvalues').val()) {
                    var array = $('#checkedvalues').val().split(",");
                    $.each(array, function (i) {
                        $("#" + array[i]).attr('checked', 'checked');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#ProductCustomCategorySave').live("click", function () {
        var ids = $('.a:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();
        bttn.siblings("input").val(ids)

        $(".customCategoriesHidden").each(function () {
            alert($(this).val())
        })

    });


</script>
```

and this the popup which gave me the list

```
public ActionResult AddInvoice(StoreTransaction data)
        {
            if(data.MainStoreId != null ){
            StoreTransaction st = new StoreTransaction();
            st.Date = data.Date;
            st.MainStoreId = data.MainStoreId;
            st.Serial = data.Serial;
            st.UserId = data.UserId;
            context.StoreTransactions.Add(st);
            context.SaveChanges();

            int lastid = (from s in context.StoreTransactions
                          orderby s.Id descending
                          select s.Id).FirstOrDefault();


            foreach (var item in data.StoreTransactionDetails)
            {
                if(item.ProductId != null)
                {
                StoreTransactionDetail std = new StoreTransactionDetail();
                std.TransactionId = lastid;
                std.ProductId = item.ProductId;
                std.UnitId = item.UnitId;
                std.Count = item.Count;
                std.Price = item.Price;
                std.TotalPrice = item.TotalPrice;
                std.Description = item.Description;
                context.StoreTransactionDetails.Add(std);
                context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            }
            return PartialView("InvoicePartial");
        }
```

and this is the action 
the problem is i have table (StoreTransaction) have list of another table (StoreTransactionDetail) which have too list of another table (StoreTransactionCustomCaregory)
in the submit action i receive the data of first two tables right but the third on i recieve it wrong

Comment: post relevent code plz

Comment: There are no miracles. In order to pass a data from client to server you should send it to the server in some way (either regular post or Ajax post or opening a web socket and pushing it thru it).

Comment: You can not send data from view to controller using ViewBag. VeiwBag is available only while view renders on the server. There is no ViewBag on Client at all.

Comment: i post all the code for you and the real problem i hope you can help me @Kartikeya

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion
On submit button

```
$( "#success" ).load( "/Controller/Action", function( response, status, xhr ) {
   if ( status == "error" ) {
      var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
      $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
   }
   else {
      //Next thing to do
   }
});

setInterval(function() {
   $("#success").load("/Controller/Action");
}, 30000); //Refreshes every 30 seconds  

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  //Turn off caching
```

To manage the synchronization time read this article
[Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Your code :set `async: false` It might work.

```
$.ajax({
           async: false,
           url: '@Url.Action("GetProductWithFullCode", "StocksTree")',
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           data: { fullcode: idforsend },
           success: function (data) {
           var radwa = $("#" + fullcodeid).parent("td").siblings("td").children(".ItemCount").attr("id")
           $("#" + radwa).val(data.Name)
           $("#" + fullcodeid).parent("td").siblings("td").children(".ItemHidden").val(data.ProductID)
      }
});
```